# Data comparison of two sensors, to produce a correction factor

Tags: cross-validation, dataset

I have sensor "A" that is outputting a set of data and I also have another sensor that is acting as the reference sensor. The aim is to get Sensor "A" as close as possible to the reference sensors. It will never be 100%

Sensor A is slightly off in terms of accuracy and we need to produce a correction factor as a percentage, which will be automated.

When we compare the results using a Correlation to produce the R-value, I get results of 0.7 to 0.75, when I add a correction factor, it always produces the same results, even if was to multiple the sensor A by 100%.

So my question is, to measure how close I can get Sensor "A" to reference data, do I need to compare mode, median and mean to get the results as close as possible?

For example when i apply the correction factor(as a percentage), i can compare the modes, median and mean of sensor "A" to reference sensor to see which factor gives the closet values?

Would this be the correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=calibration

Comment: Thanks

I have read the posts

What I am more inclined to do is compare my sensor results against the reference to see then apply a correction factor  to see how close i can get my results. Could comparing stanard diviations between two sets of data be usefull?

Comment: Yes, because that's part of an effective calibration, which involves predicting the reference based on the sensor.  Such predictions are carried out with a *regression* model.  If the sensor's response is a linear function of the true values and if the magnitude of its measurement error does not depend on the true value, then ordinary least squares is usually a good method.  The OLS formula combines the SDs of the two datasets and their correlation to produce a simple (linear) formula.

Comment: What I am doing at moment is placing my sensor data and reference data both on a graph plot.
The correlation coefficient between the data is about 0.75-0.8 as it varies from month to month, but generally, you see that trends from both plots are very similar, but the sensor is slightly off by a small factor.

Comment: So what I am doing is applying a correction sensitivity factor to sensor data and then producing its standard deviation value and then comparing it's to the SD of the reference data. I would then keep adjusting the correction factor till the SD is the closest possible.  It will never be 100% identical but close. After which you see that the sensor data overlapping the reference data on plot graphs.

Does this seem to be good approach?

Comment: It doesn't seem good to me because it's *ad hoc.*  Use of standard regression techniques will not only produce (with great computational ease) an optimal relation, but will also indicate how much it is likely to err: usually that's valuable information.

Comment: So then i use the dataset+correction factor that has least error ?